# how to get dynamic values from posting a form in the Spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a form dynamically, and I need to post it and get the values in SpringController

```
    for(var i=0;i<datArray.length;i++){
        element[i] = document.createElement("input");
        element[i].setAttribute("type", "text");
        element[i].setAttribute("name", "text");
        element[i].setAttribute("placeholder",datArray[i]);
        element[i].setAttribute("id", datArray[i]+"id");
        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");        
        //Append the element in page (in span).
        foo.appendChild(element[i]);
}
```

[image: this is my dynamic form drawn in Select onChange.]

About Pic - this is my dynamic form drawn in Select onChange

On Every dropdown Changed I am generating different text boxes dynamically. I  need to post the dynamic text boxes and get the values in the Controller Spring in JAVA.
How to get dynamically posted Values in controller?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you always sending the same model Object? I mean, does your form element always has the same name attribute?

if yes, you can just create a pojo class with attributes maching your names and use a `RequestAttribute` annotation.

If no, there is no way, you will just have to use the old requestparameter.

**UPDATE**
If you dont know what parameters are submitted, loop into all parameters :

```
    List<String> requestParameterNames = Collections.list((Enumeration<String>) request.getParameterNames());

for (String parameterName : requestParameterNames) {
    String attributeName = parameterName;
    String attributeValue = request.getParameter(parameterName);

    //DO YOUR STUFF
}
//DO YOUR STUFF
```

Comment: I doesn't know what the attributes for creating POJO. Its dynamic Form. To use Request Parameter I doesn't know what all parameters.

Comment: If you dont what parameters you are submitting, you are still able to loop the parameters name, see my update